# Existence of injective resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am quite confused about the proof of the existence of injective resolutions right know. The proof is clear to me until the crucial step, but this step is not clear at all. Maybe you can help.

> Let $A$ an object in an Abelian category $K$ with enough injectives. Then
>   $A$ has an injective resolution.

Proof: Since $K$ has enough injectives, there is an Injective object $I_0$ such that $A\overset i\hookrightarrow I_0$. Then by an axiom of abelian categories, we can complete this to an exact sequence $$0\to A\hookrightarrow I_0\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{coker} i \to0 .$$
As $K$ has enough injectives, we also get an injection $\operatorname {coker} i \hookrightarrow I_1$ to an injective object $I_1$.
I now need to construct a map from $I_0$ to $I_1$. This should follow from the fact that $I_0, I_1$ are injective. But I dont see how.

Looking at the definition of injective, I need an Object, which injects in $I_0$ and maps to $I_1$. The only object satisfying this is $A$. But the map $A\to I_1$ already factors through $I_0$ and actually it is the zero morphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map from $I_0$ to $I_1$ is the composite of the projection $I_0\to\textrm{coker}\,i$ with the injection $\textrm{coker}\,i\to I_1$.

Comment: oh, ok. Thats esier than i thought. I guess the porperty of the $I_i$ being injective only becomes relevant when computing cohomology?

Comment: As I think about it, the statement about cohomology is already encoded in the fact that this is a resolution. So why do we care about the objects being injective?

Comment: Injectivity allows to ensure functoriality properties when you pass it through a right-exact functor and take the cohomology

Comment: It might clarify the situation to observe that this proof goes through without change for *any* class $I$ of objects such that every object of $A$ admits a monomorphism into an object of $I$. Injectivity is for the applications.